# How to change date and time on simulator when using XCUITest

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, xcuitest

I need to automate some UI tests and I have to assert some results that only occur if changing the date on the simulator to a few days the future.
Does anyone know any way of doing that on the simulator without having to change the date on my mac or without using xcodebuild command line? I need to be able to change the date multiple times during my tests using different values each time.

Comment: It would be easier if you used unit tests because then you can easily add methods that change the used date in your code. Could you change theses tests to be unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way for you to test it on your app is to create an `Date` wrapper

```
class DateWrapper {
   func currentDate() -> Date {
      return Date()
   }
}
```

and mock `currentDate()` function according to your test.